# Consulta recursiva en Mysql/sql!

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, mariadb

Tengo 3 tablas:

- trabajadores (rut, nombre, sexo)
- nombres_simples (nombre,sexo)
- nombres_compuestos(nombre, sexo)

La tabla principal es *trabajadores*, algunos campos de sexo están colocados incorrectamente..  se debe comprobar el nombre de los trabajadores con las otras 2 tablas para verificar si el sexo esta puesto correctamente o no. Incluye nombres y apellidos dentro del campo nombre.
Ejemplo: 123456-3: jesus Maria Gamboa Jimenez: mujer (sexo incorrecto)

La tabla nombres_simples incluye un solo nombre con el sexo: 
ejemplo:  luis: Hombre

la tabla nombres_compuestos seria algo así el ejemplo:
jesus maria: hombre 
maria jesus: mujer

Obviamente no sale con inner join porque no hay claves para comparacion.. debe salir con like.. pero no se como hacer esa comparación recursiva de nombre con nombre.. Pienso que debería compararse primero los nombres compuestos y si no coinciden comparar con los nombres simples.**En la salida solo deben mostrarse las entradas erróneas y su sugerencia.**

En la respuesta debería mostrarse: rut, nombre, sexo actual y sexo sugerido.

Esto fue lo que probé, (y que no me funcionó):

```
SELECT B.rut, B.nombre, B.sexo as 'Sexo Actual', B.[Sexo Sugerido] as 'Sexo Sugerido'
FROM 
(
    select T0.rut, T0.nombre, T0.sexo, 
    ISNULL((select X0.sexo from nombres_simples X0 where X0.nombre = T0.nombre),ISNULL((select X0.sexo from nombres_compuestos X0 where X0.nombre = T0.nombre),'')) 'Sexo Sugerido'
    from trabajadores T0
) B
WHERE B.sexo <> B.[Sexo Sugerido]
```

Comment: ¿En la tabla trabajadores el nombre está simple o compuesto?
Por favor agrega lo que has intentado o sino no tendran en cuenta tu pregunta.

Comment: En la tabla trabajadores almacena nombre y apellido en el campo nombre.. por lo que pienso que la consulta debe realizarse con operador like.. No se me ocurren formas de probar por eso no he colocado posibles soluciones.

Comment: De acuerdo, yo ya escribí una respuesta, pero entonces dejame editarla con la informaciòn que das. Pero por favor, la proxima vez intenta hacer algo y pones en un comentario lo que se te ocurra que deberìa ir.

Comment: Vale oscar muchisimas gracias.. lo tendré en cuenta..

Answer (score 0):

Intenta esto:

```
SELECT
    t.rut,
    t.nombre,
    t.sexo sexo_actual,
    IFNULL(nc.sexo, ns.sexo) sexo_sugerido
FROM
    trabajadores t
    LEFT JOIN nombres_compuestos nc ON upper(t.nombre) = upper(nc.nombre)
    AND upper(t.sexo) != upper(nc.sexo)
    LEFT JOIN nombres_simples ns ON upper(t.nombre) != upper(nc.nombre)
    AND upper(t.nombre) LIKE CONCAT('%', upper(ns.nombre), '%')
    AND upper(t.sexo) != upper(ns.sexo)
WHERE
    upper(
        IFNULL(nc.sexo, IFNULL(ns.sexo, 'SIN COINCIDENCIAS'))
    ) != 'SIN COINCIDENCIAS';
```

De esta forma, si encuentra una asociación en nombres_compuestos toma el sexo de esta tabla, de lo contrario la toma de nombres_simples, pero sólo muestra resultados donde haya relación y que el sexo sea diferente al de trabajadores.

Comment: De la consulta algunas entradas salen repetidas y los registros con nombre "Maria Jose", algunos les sugiere sexo masculino y otros  sexo femenino. Veo entonces que la consulta está evaluando por los dos criterios y no por uno sólo como debe ser (validar si el nombre es nombre_compuesto y si no lo es buscar la sugerencia de nombre simple). Tambien deberian mostrarse sólo los nombres con sexo_sugerido diferente al sexo_actual. De todas maneras te agradezco el aporte que me has hecho :)

Comment: Muy probablemente innecesario usar `upper()`, MySQL es predeterminado a insensible a mayúsculas.

Comment: @Sal no sabía eso de mysql, pero lo dejo de todas formas que estoy acostumbrado con Oracle jeje

Comment: @LuisGonzalezR mmmm, vi que editaste la pregunta... de todos modos en un momento la corrijo.

Comment: El detalle es que Oracle puede tomar índices cuando se usan funciones en un predicado, MySQL no.

Comment: Hola. No me funcionó.Sólo arrojó un sólo resultado, cuando en realidad habían muchas coincidencias,.. Igual te agradezco un montón. A partir de tu consulta fui modificando hasta que dí con la solución.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí la estrategia sería dar prioridad a los nombres exactos y después a los similares con la función `coalesce()` que al regresar el primer valor no-nulo regresará primero a los que cumplen `=` y después a los que cumplen con `like`:

```
SELECT t.rut
     , t.nombre
     , t.sexo sexoActual
     , coalesce( ns.sexo, nc.sexo, min(nc2.sexo), min(ns2.sexo) ) sexoSugerido
  FROM trabajadores  t
    LEFT JOIN nombres_simples ns
      ON ns.nombre = t.nombre
    LEFT JOIN nombres_compuestos nc
      ON nc.nombre = t.nombre
    LEFT JOIN nombres_compuestos nc2
      ON nc2.nombre like concat('%',nc2.nombre,'%')
    LEFT JOIN nombres_simples ns2
      ON ns2.nombre like concat('%',ns2.nombre,'%')
  GROUP BY t.rut
  HAVING t.sexo <> sexoSugerido
```

Cabe resaltar que una consulta con `LIKE '%...` es de lo más costoso que te puedas encontrar, por lo que conviene combinarlo con alguna otra técnica para mejorar su desempeño.

Comment: Tarda muchísimo en ejecutarse la consulta.. aún con "LIMIT 10".  Eliminé  los dos primeros LEFT JOIN ya que las consultas con '=' no generan resultados. y aún así tarda enésima cantidad de tiempo.. Que podría hacer para agilizar la consulta?

Comment: Que función cumple el min en ésta consulta?

Comment: Habría que revisar los índices que tienes. El `min()` como función de agregación es para seleccionar un solo valor en caso de que el nombre cumpla con mas de un criterio de comparación (JOIN).